# I am getting Errors while JMS consuming in wso2esb

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I am using wso2esb4.7.0 and ActiveMQ5.8.0 http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB470/ESB+as+a+JMS+Producer and http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB470/ESB+as+a+JMS+Consumer
according to the document i have done my messages are passing well to queue.Even storing also well .While conuming the messages in to the queue Wso2esb giving issues like formats

```
ERROR - JMSMessageReceiver Unknown error processing message
org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '{' (code 123) in prolog; expected '<'
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,1]
```

why this happening is there any message format issue i am passing just sample json like

```
curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "ModifiedOn:0" -H "username:vikaash|21405735755158656" -H "password:gbin" -d '{"name":"youtility tech","mail":"faisal.shaik@youtility.in"}' http://youtility2-desktop:8282/services/JmsStore
```

how we can send response to client

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18440789/how-to-give-a-response-to-client-using-wso2esb-jmsqueue
```

Comment: Hi, can you clarify your question a bit more? Are you saying that you have progressed from the state where you were in the other SO question or still using that same configuration and having issues? Also, is the stored message in JSON format? Have you tried setting the content type to application/json similar to what is suggested in bottom of [http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB470/ESB+as+a+JMS+Consumer](http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB470/ESB+as+a+JMS+Consumer)?

Answer (score 2):

Reason for this is, if you haven't specifically configure JMS Proxy to accept messages in a particular message format, it will always treat messages are in the text/xml format.

So when you send the message in application/json format you will get this exception while building the message. So if you want to accept messages in json format from a JMS queue you have to define 'transport.jms.ContentType' parameter as follows in the proxy service configuration.

```
   <parameter name="transport.jms.ContentType">
        <rules>
            <jmsProperty>contentType</jmsProperty>
            <default>application/json</default>
        </rules>
    </parameter>
```

Following is a sample proxy configuration.

```
<proxy name="StockQuoteProxy" transports="jms">
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <property action="set" name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
        </inSequence>
        <endpoint>
            <address uri="http://localhost:9000/services/SimpleStockQuoteService"/>
        </endpoint>
        <outSequence>
            <send/>
        </outSequence>
    </target>
    <publishWSDL uri="file:repository/samples/resources/proxy/sample_proxy_1.wsdl"/>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.ContentType">
        <rules>
            <jmsProperty>contentType</jmsProperty>
            <default>application/json</default>
        </rules>
    </parameter>
</proxy>
```